# What are the auto generated methods add<propertyName>:(NSSet *)objects and add<propertyName>Object:(<object-type> *)object?

Tags: objective-c

I've never seen these methods before and they seem to be automatically generated for every property declared on a class. They can be completed in the `@implementation` of an `NSObject` subclass but I can't seem to trigger them. I can call them manually by adding the method to the header, but I can't see any change in the object.

```
#import "Example.h"

@interface Example ()

@property NSString *title;

@end

@implementation Example

-(void)addTitle:(NSSet *)objects
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

-(void)addTitleObject:(NSString *)object
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

@end
```

Edit: I've found the source of the completion in clang's source (SemaCodeComplete.cpp) in the "Unordered Setters" section. There's also an "Unordered Getters" section. Interestingly there's also an autocompleted method `intersectKey:(NSSet *)objects`, where key is the name of the property. Weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like they're there to support Core Data. [This](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002154) document lists the methods under "Custom To-Many Relationship Accessor Methods". Earlier in the same document it's stated that "Core Data does this even for entities represented by NSManagedObject". Either this is a typo and it's supposed to say "even for entities not represented" or there's a bug in the autocompletion that generates these methods for non NSManagedObject objects.